# Gradle project sync failed on Android Studio 3.1.3 (June 4 updated) in Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, gradle, build.gradle

I have updated my android-studio now after that, I'm getting this error
**Gradle project sync failed**. I even tried to import other Gradle distributions on Android Studio via File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle > Use local gradle distribution

But still, I'm facing the same issue.

[image]

Comment: I guess you've already tried File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart. You could delete all the files in the ~/.gradle directory and download the dependencies again. It sometimes solves random Gradle issues.

Comment: @Harisudhan For temporary change you can downgrade the android studio version like File --> Project Structure -> Project